# Timer is not counting down in Fixed position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing one game app in HTML5 for android devices. In that game I am using simple count down method with setInterval method and I am displaying that counter in timer div. When I make div element position is fixed then count down is not running whenever I touched the screen then only count down starts and stops. BUT this is running good in absolute position, I don't want to make that div as absolute. I have tried all the possibilities, No luck
Please any one help me to resolve this problem

Here is my code

HTML:

```
<div id="time">
    <p id="txt2"></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#time {
    right: 150px;
    top: 11px;
    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

JS:

```
function timedCount(){
    sec = 119 - c;
    document.getElementById("txt2").innerHTML = sec;
    c=c+1;
    tt=setTimeout(function(){
        timedCount()
    },10000);

}
function doTimer(){
    //alert("TImer starts");
    if (!timer_is_on){
        timer_is_on=1;
        timedCount();
    }
}
function stopCount(){
    //alert("Timer stops");
    clearTimeout(tt);
    timer_is_on=0;
//c = 0;
}
```

Please check this one I refered http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_stop

Comment: Please create a fiddle: jsfiddle.net

Comment: It looks like `c` is never set. Try adding `c=0;` as a global before the functions.

Comment: I don't think it's positioning problem.

Comment: @Paul Code is correct.. I have some other code also so i copied and paste.. After touch the screen only counter runs other else counter will be idle only..

Comment: @IamDesai I am running it in mobile devices

Comment: @C-link If I change position fixed to absolute then it will run correctly BUT div will be keep on moving so I want the div should be in fixed position

Comment: @IamDesai please check jsfiddle link here http://jsfiddle.net/tpdqv/

Answer (score 1):

Try this one with jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#time {
right: 150px;
top: 11px;
z-index: 999;
position: fixed;
font-size: 30px;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 30px;
color: red;
   }  
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
var c=1, timer_is_on = 0, tt;
$(document).ready(function(){
  doTimer();


function doTimer() {
    if (!timer_is_on){
        timer_is_on=1;
        timedCount();
    }

}


function timedCount() {

    var sec = 119 - c;
    $("#txt2").html(sec);
   //alert(c);
    c = c + 1;
    tt = setTimeout(function () {
        timedCount()
    }, 10000);

}

function stopCount() {
    //alert("Timer stops");
    clearTimeout(tt);
    timer_is_on = 0;
    //c = 0;
}
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="time">
   <p id="txt2"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Check this** [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tpdqv/)

Comment: Same code only I am using sir BUT problem is count down is not running in screen idle, If I touch screen then count down run and stops, If I keep on touch my screen then it will be running or else NOT